# Does going from one Action method to the other action method clear class variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So in the same controller I have a Login Action method like this:

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {

        LoginModel model = this.LoginManager.LoadLoginPageData();
        this.ForgotPasswordMethod = model.ForgotPasswordMethod;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Notice I set a variable there:  `ForgotPasswordMethod`

So now when there on that page if they click on a link, it call another action result in the same controller class like this:

```
public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ForgotPasswordMethod) && this.ForgotPasswordMethod.Trim().ToUpper() == "TASKS")
        return View();

    return null;  //todo change later.
}
```

Notice I tried to read the value of ForgotPasswordMethod , but it was `NULL` but it is NOT null when I am in the `Login() method.` So what should I do?

Comment: You could use `TempData`.

Comment: Everytime an MVC action process a request, a new instance of the controller is created. The object you had when login was called is not the same you have when ForgotPassword is called. it´s stateless as http. If you put a constructor method with a breakpoint in your controller and debug you can see it will be called everytime.

Answer (score 2):

`ASP.NET MVC` was designed to return back to a cleaner, more straightforward web world built on HTTP, which is stateless, meaning that there is no "memory" of what has previously occurred unless you specifically use a technique that ensures otherwise.

As a result, whatever state you set via one ActionResult will no longer be the same state that exists when another ActionResult is invoked.

How do you "fix" this?  You have a variety of options, depending on what your needs are:

- Render the value to the client and post the value back to your second ActionResult method.
- Store the value as a header and check that header.
- Store the value in a cookie and check the cookie.
- Store the value in session.
- Store the value in a database.
- Store the value in a static dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

what if you store forgotpasswordmethod in Viewbag like

```
 public ActionResult Login()
{
    LoginModel model = this.LoginManager.LoadLoginPageData();
    Viewbag.ForgotPasswordMethod = model.ForgotPasswordMethod;
    return View(model);
}
```

then in the link of your page you can pass the value from the ViewBag

```
<a href=@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Name of your Controller", new { methodName = ViewBag.ForgotPasswordMethod })>Forgot Password</a>
```

Change your forgotpassword to

```
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string methodName)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(methodName) && methodName.Trim().ToUpper() == "TASKS")
    return View();

    return null;  //todo change later.
}
```